# <table mat-table> tag is not printing anything out

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am making an app to display some user information and I am trying to use the angular/materials library to make a table. For some reason, the mat-table will not even print out the titles of the columns.

I have tried to change the type of the data source array and also tried the other implementation of the mat table using the  tag as opposed to the

I have put a simplified version of my code on stackblitz,
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7mztmg

Please take a look at the panel component, as that is where the relevant code is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using this:

```
 <th mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="tableColumns"></th>
 <td mat-row *matRowDef="let user; columns: tableColumns"></td>
```

replace with:

```
 <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="tableColumns"></tr>
 <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let user; columns: tableColumns"></tr>
```